# How to force js code to execute in the written order?

Tags: jquery, show, slidetoggle

```
$("#btnGall").click(function() {
    $('#gall').slideToggle('slow');
    $("#gInfo").show();
});
```

Why this code executes firstly the second line, and then the first one.
I don't want to show `#gInfo` before slideToggle is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the function from an anonymous function specified as the success callback passed into the slidetoggle function.

```
$("#btnGall").click(function() {
    $('#gall').slideToggle('slow', function(){
        $("#gInfo").show();
    });
});
```

[SlideToggle Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2zn6G/

Answer (score 2):

That's because animations are asynchronous, and the script does'nt wait for them to finish (thank God). There are built in callbacks for this specific use added to most jQuery functions that do animations :

```
$("#btnGall").click(function() {
    $('#gall').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $("#gInfo").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Slide toggle allows for a call back after the operation is completed

```
$("#btnGall").click(function() {
    $('#gall').slideToggle('slow', function () {    $("#gInfo").show();});

});
```